# I need to traverse an object and return some values from it recursively

Tags: javascript, recursion, traversal

I'm getting stuck when I pass the optional 2nd parameter to 'listFiles'. I'm struggling to find out how to list the files inside a given sub-directory. List the files in a given directory, of a file-system described by data. So, you should be able to return a list of files from the data.

Parameters:

`data {Object}` - a file system object as described above

`dirName {String}` - a directory name the files are desired to be listed from.

**Note:** This parameter is optional. If it is not provided, list ALL files.

`Returns {Array}` The files under the directory dirName, including sub-directories.

The approach to complete this exercise should be using recursion. I was able to return all the files from the file system object with the code below:

```js
const fileData = {
  dirName: 'app',
  files: ['index.html'],
  subDirs: [{
      dirName: 'js',
      files: [
        'main.js',
        'app.js',
        'misc.js',
      ],
      subDirs: [{
        dirName: 'vendor',
        files: [
          'jquery.js',
          'underscore.js',
        ],
        subDirs: [],
      }, ],
    },
    {
      dirName: 'css',
      files: [
        'reset.css',
        'main.css',
      ],
      subDirs: [],
    },
  ],
};

function listFiles(data, dirName) {

    let result = [];

    const traverseFileSystem = (obj) => {
      Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
        if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
          if (key === 'files') {
            result = [...result, ...obj[key]];
          }
          traverseFileSystem(obj[key]);
        }
      });
    };

    traverseFileSystem(data);

    console.log(result);
  }

listFiles(fileData, 'js');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
const trFS= dir=> dir.dirName==dirName ? dir : dir.subDirs.flatMap(d=> trFS(d));

const trFSNoDir = dir => [...dir.subDirs.flatMap(d=> trFSNoDir(d)), ...dir.files];
```

```js
const fileData = {
  dirName: 'app',
  files: ['index.html'],
  subDirs: [{
      dirName: 'js',
      files: [
        'main.js',
        'app.js',
        'misc.js',
      ],
      subDirs: [{
        dirName: 'vendor',
        files: [
          'jquery.js',
          'underscore.js',
        ],
        subDirs: [],
      }, ],
    },
    {
      dirName: 'css',
      files: [
        'reset.css',
        'main.css',
      ],
      subDirs: [],
    },
  ],
};

function listFiles(data, dirName) {

    const trFS= dir=> dir.dirName==dirName ? dir : dir.subDirs.flatMap(d=> trFS(d));
    
    const trFSNoDir = dir => [...dir.subDirs.flatMap(d=> trFSNoDir(d)), ...dir.files];
    
    return dirName ? trFS(data)[0] : trFSNoDir(data);        
}

console.log("dir name: js\n", listFiles(fileData, 'js'));
console.log("dir name: css\n", listFiles(fileData, 'css'));
console.log("dir name: -\n",listFiles(fileData));
```

When dirName is given I return object (instead of array) with files and subdirectories because you not specified how output array should looks like (e.g. does subdirectories in that array should be objects or names only) - this object can be mapped in easy way to array (e.g. if `r` contains result then by `[...r.files,...r.subDirs]`).

Comment: Nice approach! Thanks. But I'm trying to return all the files, including the ones in their children.

e.g When I pass 'js' it should be returns the files in 'vendor' as well.

Comment: Thanks! That was fast!!

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution:

```js
function listFiles(data,dirName,level){
  var files=[];
  if(!level){
    level=0;
    data=[data];
  }
  for(var item of data){
    var subDirs=item.subDirs;
    if(subDirs && subDirs.length){
      files=files.concat(listFiles(subDirs,dirName,level+1));
    }
    if(dirName && item.dirName !== dirName){
      continue;
    }
    
    files.push(item);
   
  }
  return files;
}
```